# Go to position of ArrayList according to month

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` which contains HTML files according to month. What I am trying to accomplish is, let say if current month is Jan, then the first of the list is jan.html, followed by feb.html, mar.html, etc. If current month is Feb, the position of `ArrayList` will directly move to the second one, which is feb.html, followed by mar.html and preceded by jan.html.

```
mListViews = new ArrayList<View>();
        addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/jan.html");
        addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/feb.html");
        addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/mar.html");
        addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/apr.html");
        addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/may.html");
        addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/jun.html");
        addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/jul.html");
        addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/aug.html");
        addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/sep.html");
        addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/oct.html");
        addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/nov.html");
        addView(mListViews, "file:///android_asset/dec.html");
```

This is my `addView`:

```
private void addView(List<View> viewList,String url)
    {
        WebView webView=new WebView(this);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        viewList.add(webView);
    }
```

I know I need to use

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
if (month == 0) {
do something
}
else if (month == 1) {
do something
}
```

However, I have no idea on the "do something" part. Is it possible for me to do this?

Comment: Is `addView()` method your custom method? Please give method here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly get the item from Arraylist (if list is populated)
using `get(index)`
no need for if statement

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mListViews.get(month);
```

**EDIT:**
by default ArrayList will add items in order
with index =0, then 1, ...etc

unless you really need to set the index when adding, you don't need to do it

you will have to modify the function addView() as following:

```
private void addView(int index, List<View> viewList,String url)
    {
        WebView webView=new WebView(this);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        viewList.add(index,webView);
    }
```

and when calling addView(), just like this

```
addView(0, mListViews, "file:///android_asset/jan.html");
addView(1, mListViews, "file:///android_asset/feb.html");
```

but again, passing, 0, 1, 2 ... is the default for arrayList
it will change nothing unless you want to change the order of month-name with index

**EDIT2:**

i think you need to use [Collections.rotate()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_rotate.htm)
revert the old code, and after adding all items to list
rotate the list to current month,
a lucky guess would be

```
Collections.rotate(mListViews , mListViews.size()-month);
```

you need to read more about it and do some trials.

Comment: Do you mind to share how to use the `get(index)`. I am a self learner and my knowledge is limited.

Comment: After reading, I have understand about `get(index)`, but I am facing another problem. How to send the position to `add(View)`? Let say in February, I should send the position 2 to `add(View`.

Comment: it's already mentioned how to use get() last line in above answer, and the regarding other question, you don't need to set index when adding, they will get index by order of add, so 1st added will be index=0, and so on, if you want to set specific index for each item, you need to pass another param (index0 to addView() and use it in `viewList.add(index, webView);`

Comment: Sorry, how to pass another param (index0 to addView() and use it in viewList.add(index, webView);? I will appreciate if you can show me any tutorial.

Comment: @user2872856 check the answer again, EDIT was added

Comment: Thank you. But actually what I want is, let say current month is Feb. So I would like the ArrayList to start at feb.html and jan.html will become the previous one. I tried this, but seem that I can't put -1 as value.
`addView(-1, mListViews, "file:///android_asset/jan.html");`
`addView(0, mListViews, "file:///android_asset/feb.html");`

Comment: check answer, i added EDIT2, i have never worked with rotate before, just play around with it.